# What is the meaning of default_constructible range adaptors in C++23?

Tags: c++, std-ranges, c++23

Since C++23, `view`s are no longer required to be `default_constructible`. For range adaptors such as `views::filter` and `views::transform`, their default constructor is [redefined](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter.view) as:

```
template<input_­range V, indirect_­unary_­predicate<iterator_t<V>> Pred>
  requires view<V> && is_object_v<Pred>
class filter_view : public view_interface<filter_view<V, Pred>> {
private:
  V base_ = V();                              // exposition only
  copyable-box<Pred> pred_;                   // exposition only
public:
  filter_view() requires default_­initializable<V> && default_­initializable<Pred> = default;
};
```

And because the default constructor of `ref_view` has been deleted in [p2325r3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2325r3.html), this indicates that range adapters applied into lvalue `range`s such as `std::vector` are [no longer](https://godbolt.org/z/K4eoE3e8s) `default_constructible`:

```
std::vector v{1, 2, 3};
auto r = v | std::views::filter([](auto) { return true; });
decltype(r){}; // ok in C++20, error in C++23
```

Only when range adapters are applied into `default_constructible` `view`s such as `std::string_view` or `views::iota(0)`, the returned views can be `default_constructible`:

```
auto r = std::views::iota(0) | std::views::filter([](auto) { return true; });
decltype(r){}; // ok in C++20 and C++23
```

But regarding these cases, I really can’t think of the use cases to make these `view`s `default_constructible` even if that is feasible. If we construct a `view` by default, it means that we construct an empty `view`, and it is obviously meaningless to apply range adaptors to the empty `view`s:

```
constexpr auto r = std::views::iota(0, 10)
                 | std::views::transform([](auto x) { return x; });
static_assert(!std::ranges::empty(r));
// views::iota is default-constructible, so r is also default-constructible
static_assert( std::ranges::empty(decltype(r){}));
```

In my opinion, the default constructor of range adaptors in C++20 is just to satisfy the `view`, since the `view` is no longer required to be `default_constructible` in C++23, there is no need for the default constructors of these adapters to existing.

Why is the default constructor of these range adaptors not deleted in C++23 but make into a constraint function? Is there really a case that requires it to be `default_constructible`? What are the considerations behind this?

Comment: C++23 is *not at thing* yet, so there is no "since C++23".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The status quo before this paper is that views simply *have* to be default constructible, even if that isn't a meaningful requirement that can be fulfilled by the view, leading it to have a singular state that can only be assigned to. That wasn't very useful (and indeed harmful), which is why that requirement was removed.

But now that views simply *can* be default constructible, there is the question of *when* you should make a range adaptor default constructible. And the answer to that question is more straightforward: why wouldn't you make it default constructible if you could?

If you're `transform`ing a view, `V`, that is default constructible (and presumably `V` is default constructible in a way that has a meaningful state - which isn't infeasible: a default-constructed `string_view` is a valid empty range) and your function `F` is also default constructible (as, say, any capture-less lambda is in C++20), then `transform_view<V, F>` really should also be default constructible. There really isn't much reason for it *not* to be, it's effectively free to conditionally provide that constructor, and it can't cause harm.

So between *not* providing a default constructor and *conditionally* providing a default constructor where it would be sensible to do so, the latter just seems like a more user-friendly choice.

Otherwise, from the perspective of the library, you'd have to be able to somehow guarantee that default constructing such range adaptors would *never* be useful... and I'm not sure you could do that?

---

Note that this is not a new library feature for C++23, but rather a defect against C++20.